# What is the purpose of SpanQuery in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

Can someone explain what a `SpanQuery` is, and what are typical use cases for it?

The [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_7_3/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) is very laconic, and keeps mentioning the concept of "span", which I'm not quite sure I get.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spans provide a [proximity search](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/package-summary.html#package_description) feature to Lucene. They are used to find multiple terms near each other, without requiring the terms to appear in a specified order. You can specify the terms that you want to find, and how close they must be. You can combine these span queries with each other or with other types of Lucene queries.

Comment: How is the different to a query with a slop?

Comment: This is useful http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/

Comment: Current link for above comment: https://lucidworks.com/blog/the-spanquery/

Comment: @Joel 'query with a slop' can use search-time analyser, but span can't use. span has in_order feature , which is missing in query with slop

Comment: The working link I find for spanquery https://massiveprogramming.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-spanquery-lucidworks.html

Answer (score 5):

Found [this](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) all about the SpanQuery

Comment: Current link: https://lucidworks.com/blog/the-spanquery/

Answer (score 4):

A span query is a query that returns infomation about *where* in a document each match took place.  You use the getSpans() method to get the locations.

The following deck of slides (unfortunately in Powerpoint) contain an example: http://www.cnlp.org/apachecon2005/AdvancedLucene.ppt

Answer (score 2):

The javadocs you linked to are for a class in the " org.apache.lucene.search.spans " package.  if you had clicked on the "package" link on those javadocs you would have been taken to...

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/package-summary.html

...where the concept of Spans and what a Span is are explained in depth.